# How to Extract header value from POST response in Java?

Tags: java, post, response

I have implemented an api to add an entry in mysql server. After creation of entry in database, it returns a 201 response. 
I want to extract the Id from the header.

for Example

This is my post response

```
Response::::HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 201  [Vary: Origin, Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method, Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers, Vary: Origin, Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method, Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers, Location: http://localhost:8080/v1/manager/17, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, Pragma: no-cache, Expires: 0, X-Frame-Options: DENY, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Date: Wed, 13 May 2020 11:24:57 GMT, Keep-Alive: timeout=20, Connection: keep-alive] ResponseEntityProxy{[Chunked: true]}}
```

Location: http://localhost:8080/v1/manager/17
I want to extract 17 which is the ID from Location tag in Java. How to achieve this?

Comment: Why not make the 17 a parameter and basically change the url to be something like: http://localhost:8080/v1/manager?id=17 then you can just extract the id parameter from the post

Comment: https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-response-header-in-java/

Comment: Thank you @OldProgrammer The link worked for me